# How can I tell if a model has not been changed in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

This may be a result of misuse of the component, though I don't think so.
I have an issue where a View updates a model in Backbone JS and calls the model's Set method so that it may verify it's input.
In theory there are two results to such an action: Error and Change.
Both events work as prescribed.
But in fact there is a third event: No change.
That is, if the input has not been changed at all, I can't tell after calling Set because no error will be thrown but nor will a change event, as nothing has actually changed- but I still want to know about such a case.
Is there a way for me to do this?

The reason is that there is an action I want performed only if no error occurs, but there is no way for me to know (without a change event) that the model has attempted to set the new values and ended with no result as it all happens asynchronously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every Backbone model has a [`hasChanged` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-hasChanged):

> **hasChanged** `model.hasChanged([attribute])`
>
> Has the model changed since the last `"change"` event? If an **attribute** is passed, returns `true` if that specific attribute has changed.

Perhaps you can use that to check your third possibility.

BTW, the callbacks aren't asynchronous. The error and changed callbacks are triggered and return before [`set` returns](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L184):

```
set : function(attrs, options) {
  //...

  // Run validation.
  if (!options.silent && this.validate && !this._performValidation(attrs, options)) return false;

  //...

  // Update attributes.
  for (var attr in attrs) {
    var val = attrs[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(now[attr], val)) {
      now[attr] = val;
      delete escaped[attr];
      this._changed = true;
      if (!options.silent) this.trigger('change:' + attr, this, val, options);
    }
  }
```

The `_performValidation` call triggers the error callbacks, the `this.trigger` calls will call the per-attribute callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression it was asynchronous.
I'll try using hasChanged...

Comment: @Che: Anything that hits the server (`sync`, `save`, ...) will be asynchronous, anything that happens only in the browser will be synchronous and sequential.

Comment: Look at the code posted above. hasChanged() looks for `this._changed` which does not get touched if you do not set the model to a new value.  So this will not work.

Comment: @maxl0rd: And that's the third state that the OP is interested in so you're not making any sense.

Comment: @muistooshort sorry I was unclear. What I meant to illustrate is that _changed, or hasChanged() is only useful in the brief blip during an event handler on a change event. Since these won't be fired in all cases, there is no constructive time to inspect that property in his use case.

Comment: @maxl0rd: But `this._changed` is valid after the `set` call returns and that's what `hasChanged` looks at; `this._changing`, OTOH, is only valid during the brief window while the change is taking place. The real problem is that the OP wants the absence of an event to be an event itself and that's not easy to do. Checking `hasChanged` before and after should do the trick but it is hard to say given the limited information available.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may need to dance around `Model.set()` a little bit to get where you want. If you are using this functionality, then you should have defined a `validate()` method on your model.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate

So you can call this method directly...

```
// something happens and we need to update the model to "newvalues"
if (model.validate(newvalues)) {
  model.trigger('error')
} else {
  model.trigger('change')
}
model.set(newvalues)
```

That way you will always at least get 'change' or 'error' out of it, even if it's the same. You will also still get the existing events from set.